# Adding a value from input to a div

Tags: php, javascript

I have the below code that im trying to add the search results to a div by clicking on the result.  Let me know if anyone can assist, I looked at the code about a hundred times and can't seem to figure out why it wont work.  I have tried placing the javascript below the div, below the body, and in the head, no dice. Below is the PHP, javascript, and HTML.  Thanks.

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var oButton = document.getElementById('addData');
      var data = document.getElementById('dataInput');
      var display = document.getElementById('display');

      oButton.onclick = function() {
         display.innerHTML += data.value + "<br />";
      }
   </script>
```

**PHP:**

```
echo '<button id="addData">','<input id="dataInput" type="hidden" value="'.$results_row['username'].'" />','<div id="testt">', '<h3>', $results_row['username'],'</h3>','</div>','</button>';
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id ="search_results"></div>
    <p>
                      <div id="display"></div> 

                    </p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="search.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well your `<button id="addData">` seems to come *after* your script that binds to it.  Maybe you should start with that.

Comment: Are u sure `$results_row['username']` contain any value?

Comment: yes, they do.  I checked in the html output

Comment: I tried with hard coded values for `$results_row['username']`and its works fine

Comment: could it be a conflict with jquery? if so, do you know the jquery equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get the result in server-side code then below code should be the solution. try it.

```
 <input type="hidden" id="dataInput" value="This is my hidden value">

    <div id="display"></div> 


  <input type="button" name="oButton" id="oButton" onClick="fnc()" value="click">

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function fnc()
 {
   var oButton = document.getElementById("addData");
   var data = document.getElementById("dataInput");
   var display = document.getElementById("display");


     display.innerHTML += data.value + "<br />";
   }
```

Comment: i dont want the input type ="text" I want it to be hidden

Comment: same thing. You fetch the result and write it in a hidden field. do it in php

Comment: thats what I did, I have the PHP in my original post.

Comment: sorry if im not understanding, feel like im missing your point

Comment: ok then debug it.look up the hidden variable whether there is data or not. If there is then there must be a problem with your JS

Comment: there is data in the hidden variable.

Comment: could it be conflict with jquery? and do you know a jquery solution that is the same as above?

Comment: I've edited my code. Now i am fetching the value from a hidden variable. So this should do now

Comment: thanks for sticking with me.  The last edit works like a charm. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

set the javascript in an onload block

```
window.onload = function(e){ 
      var oButton = document.getElementById('addData');
      var data = document.getElementById('dataInput');
      var display = document.getElementById('display');

      oButton.onclick = function() {
         data = document.getElementById('dataInput'); // make sure the value is updated
         display.innerHTML += data.value + "<br />";
      }
}
```

This way you can be sure you can assign an onclick function to oButton.
And also make sure you update the data, since otherwise it'll contain the "initial" data all the time (which is probably '')

Answer (score 0):

This is what you expected,use your `.$results_row['username'].` value Instead of my hard-coded value:

```
<p><div id="display"></div></p>

<?php echo '<button id="addData" onClick="fnc()">','<input id="dataInput" type="hidden" value="Hardcoded value" />','<div id="testt">', '<h3>', 'Hardcoded value','</h3>','</div>','</button>'; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function fnc()
 {
  var oButton = document.getElementById("addData");
  var data = document.getElementById("dataInput");
  var display = document.getElementById("display");

  display.innerHTML += data.value + "<br />";
 }
</script>
```